# JSON object to String in Swift

Tags: json, swift, string

I have spend a lot of time googling and I could not get a solution to work so I hope someone can help me.

I have a string called user which is of type: < hit>JSON. I can get information out of it by using:

> user.object["displayname"] ?? ""

This works fine however it gives me the result between "". So if someones displayname is stackoverflowuser it will give me: "stackoverflowuser". Is there a way to get this as a string without the ""?

Edit:

I use the following API:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/#examples.

This is my code to get the user object:

```
index.search(query: "\(searchtext)") { result in
   if case .success(let response) = result {
      for user in response.hits {
         let resultDisplayname = "\(user.object["displayname"] ?? "")"

      }
   }
 }
```

The resultDisplayname is an example of a variable that I want to turn into a String.

Comment: Is there something wrong with, for example, "chrispsv"? Cause it's swift syntax. Check this documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string#2919514

Comment: Well the problem is that if I want to show someones username it is between "". And that just doesn't look good. Also if I want to show someones profilepicture. The link to the url is also between "". This way the url doesn't work and I can't show the picture.

Comment: So what I can do is remove the first and last character of the string (because those are the "") but that is an ugly solution.

Comment: What do you mean `show someones username`? If you got the string from `displayname` and set to label, like, nameLabel.text = user.object["displayname"] ?? "". It will work perfectly.

Comment: If I add .text behind it I get the following error in xcode: "Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'text'"

Comment: aw, are you using SwiftyJSON lib, or which kind of third party to parse JSON?

Comment: To be honest I don't know. I'm using the Algolia search engine which gives me some kind of JSON format but I don't know how to see which lab that is.

Comment: Provide more informations, which kind of `user` is, JSON type, what is that?

Comment: I added my code to make more clear what kind user is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's assume your JSON is like this format

```swift
{
    "displayname": "chrispv",
    "age": 30
}
```

Create a swift object to represent it

```swift
struct Person: Decodable {
    let displayname: String
    let age: Int
}
```

Then execute your search query using object above

```swift
index.search(query: "\(searchtext)") { result in
    if case .success(let response) = result {
        do {
            let persons: [Person] = try response.extractHits()
            for person in persons {
                print(person.displayname)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Decoding error")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand this is the best solution. However it is very hard to create a struct of the query result since the user returns a very complicated JSON format. Is there a way to create a struct that is flexible?

Comment: I think it's better if the data model mapping 1-1 with JSON structure. However, you can just take what you really need. In this scenario, remove `age` and keep `displayname` it's ok. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed my issue!! I did not know that it was possible to decode JSON in a struct that wasn't mapped 1-1!

Comment: It's no big deal.